# Add data attribute to current and future links

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have the following code:

```
$('a.my-class').data('my-attribute', 'my-value')
```

How can I do so the `my-attribute` data attribute gets added to all *future* links also? I thought of using:

```
$('a.my-class').on('event', 'selector', function(){})
```

or even the parent:

```
$('.parent-of-a').on('event', 'selector', function(){})
```

but I have no clue what event/selector I need to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```js
    $('a.my-class').each(function(){
        $(this).data('my-attribute', 'my-value')
    });
    

    $(".add-links").click(function(){
        var lbl=$(".label").val();
        var myattribute=$(".my-attribute").val();
        $(".container").append("<a href='#'my-attribute='"+myattribute+"' class='my-class'>"+lbl+"</a>");
    });
```

```css
.add-links{
  padding:10px;
  background:#0077CC;
  color:#fff;
 display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


</div>
Link Label:<input type="text" class="label"/><br/>
Attribute:<input type="text" class="my-attribute"/><br/>

<span class="add-links">Add Links</span>
```

Comment: This does not fully answer my concerns.

Comment: Actually what you mean

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want my data attribute to be added to _future_ links also, not just to the ones existing in the DOM at that specific moment.

Comment: How you add the future links?

Comment: By whatever dynamic method jQuery provides.

Comment: You're basically repeating yourself and that's exactly what I don't want to. I don't control how links are added to the page so I need to hook somehow to the existing snippet that adds data-attributes on links.